# unique_ptr does not see custom constructor for derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
class A{
    string m_name;
    int m_num;
public:
    A(string name="", int number=0) : m_name(name), m_num(number)
    { cout << "ctorA " << m_name << endl; }

    virtual ~A(){ cout << "dtorA " << m_name << endl; }

    string getName(){ return m_name; }
    void setName(const string name){ m_name = name; }
    int getNumber(){ return m_num; }
};

class B : public A{
    string m_s;
public:
    B(string name="", int number=0, string s="")
        : A(name, number){ m_s = s; }

    string getS(){ return m_s; }

};


auto upB = unique_ptr<B>("B", 2, "B");   //ERROR HERE


error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<B>::unique_ptr(const char [2], int, const char [2])'
```

I don't understand why it doesn't see the B constructor. All seems fine to me.  Works with default constructor as such:

```
auto upB = unique_ptr<B>();
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there some special issue with derived classes?

Comment: Have you tried consulting suitable [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to find out how `std::unique_ptr` can be initialised?

Comment: Stupid mistake, wish I could delete post.  Was just too tired to see typo.  I wanted to type make_unique and typed unique_ptr by mistake.

Comment: Is it possible to delete this?  I don't want to clutter stack with a typo question.  I just didn't see the typo.  Typed make_unique so much my eyes glazzed right over it as much as I've looked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
auto upB = std::make_unique<B>("B", 2, "B");
```

or

```
auto upB = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B("B", 2, "B"));
```

Below empty `std::unique_ptr<B>` is created, it is like `nullptr`.

```
auto upB = unique_ptr<B>();
```

Comment: Gees.  Doh. I know how to use it, just too much coding today.  I didn't see it, my eyes glazed right over it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why it doesn't see the B constructor.

Note that `unique_ptr<B>("B", 2, "B");` is not trying to invoke the `B`'s constructor, but [`std::unique_ptr`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have such constructor then compiling fails.

I think you want

```
auto upB = unique_ptr<B>(new B("B", 2, "B"));
```

i.e. passing a pointer with type `B*` to construct a `unique_ptr<B>`; you can also use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), which will forward the arguments to the constructor of `B` to construct an object of type `B` and wrap it in a `std::unique_ptr`.

```
auto upB = make_unique<B>("B", 2, "B");
```

And about `auto upB = unique_ptr<B>();`, you're constructing a `std::unique_ptr` that owns nothing via `std::unique_ptr`'s default constructor.